# Matplotlib - want to plot functions centered around the middle of the x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, visualization

```
import numpy as np
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

def sig(a, x):
    return 1 / (1 + math.exp(-a*x))
def cos(x):
    return (math.cos(x)+1)/2

a = []
b = []
c = []
j = np.arange(-math.pi,0, 0.0001)
g = np.arange(-math.pi,0, 0.0002)
k = np.arange(-math.pi,0, 0.0010)



csvfile = "data.csv"
idx, value =  "Index","Value"
csvRow = [idx, value]
with open(csvfile, "w", newline='') as fp:
    wr = csv.writer(fp, dialect = "excel")
    wr.writerow(csvRow)


    for i in range(0, len(j), 1):
        a.append(cos(j[i]))
        ##wr.writerow([i,sig(g, j[i])])

    for i in range(0, len(g), 1):
        b.append(cos(g[i]))

    for i in range(0, len(k), 1):
        c.append(cos(k[i]))

    fp.close()

plt.plot(a)
plt.plot(b)
plt.plot(c) 

plt.show()
```

I want to plot these three cos functions for comparing the steepness. To accomplish this I want to have all the functions centered around the middle of the x axis, how can I achieve this?
[Currently the plot looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5gPR.png)

Comment: Can you show an example of how you would like the plot to look?

Comment: What's "the middle of the x axis"?

Comment: @DavidG Something like this imgur.com/RTDcYmo

Comment: You plot only the y values of your curves. Consider that plotting a point in 2D space needs an `x` and `y` coordinate. In your case specify `x` such as to get the `y`values at the positions you want them to be, then `plot(x,y)`.